# When and why we use list view instead of scrollview in Android?

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I understand we always use listview to display list of items instead of Scrollview. But I know we can do it with scrollview also. I understand that performance of list view is better than ScrollView when you want to display list of items. My question is there are any reason for that also? And why nobody use scrollview to display list of items? Please give me your opinion. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often use Scrollview for displaying a limit of items, this number rarely be changed on runtime, such as in a configuration page. Otherwise, ListView is for display a lot of items. Those items may be the same type such as a list of Students, Messages, etc.

Answer (score 2):

ListView uses a concept of dequeueing that is removing view from the view hierarchy when they are not visible. For example if you have 20 items and only 10 are visible at a time.

> The listview will remove the top 1st element when 11th element comes
>   into view using scrolling. This reduces memory load and gives smoother
>   performance. Battery consumption is major factor of phone these days
>   and no one wants a app that consumes all the phone battery.

Scrollview on the other hand keeps all the view added in it in the view heirarchy all the time therefore increased memory usage and performance issues when the number of views added are huge.

Comment: i have one more doubt.Is a good way to put ScrollView inside ListView?

Comment: @AshwiniBhat modern UI require complex view hierarchy and its now common to see scrollview used inside listview like horizontal scrollable images. so yes, you can use them. (its considered good from UX point of view)

Comment: ya in my APP used. But thing is if try to scroll in between the ListView the Parent ScrollView not working?do you know why this happening? used MotionEvent also for Action UP & Down @shubhank

Comment: maybe discuss your issue in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow) ?

Comment: @AshwiniBhat `Is a good way to put ScrollView inside ListView?` **NO**. Never put a scrollable View inside another one!

Comment: @BobMalooga okay you are correct, there is view pager which kinda works same as horizontal scrollview. you should use that rather then scrollview. Basically find any other scrollable component that does the kinda same job and isnt memory intensive.

Comment: ALL scrollable Views should NEVER contain another one. Because of scrolling conflicts.

Comment: play store app seems to have scrollable view with a scrollable top horizontal image layout. i dont see that being achievable both side scrolling without having one scrollview inside another.

Comment: @Bob Malooga ya not working but some people telling it works & some people not if u try to scroll in between the Listview the full page will not scroll this issue am facing do you have idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @AshwiniBhat Simple: DON'T put a scrolalble View inside another one. Reengineer your UI.

Answer (score 1):

[ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) is used to put different or same child views or layouts and the all can be scrolled.

[ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) is used to put same child view or layout as multiple items. All these items are also scrollable.

A scrollview on the other hand is quite different. You add other views to a scrollview which allows you to have more elements than what would fit on screen. Say, for example, you wanted to have 50 buttons or a large chunk of text. By using a listview you have a container that is the size of the screen but allows the user to scroll up and down to see the other views.